# mysql getting column name and compare with another table

Tags: mysql

i got two tables

> table A

```
Date | A001 | B001
-------------------
2020 |  2   |  3
```

> table b

```
ItemCode | ItemName
---------------------
   A001  |   candy
   B001  |   Apple
```

is it possible to select the number from table A and also the actual itemName from table B? 
A statment in english would be something like

```
select * from table A and itemName from table B where TableA's columnName = TableB's ItemName;
```

Comment: If you mean without specifying the column name as a constant then no it's not possible without dynamic sql. but why do you want to an what do you expect your output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

If I followed you correctly, you can do:

```
select a.*, ba.item_name item_name_a, bb.item_name item_name_b
from a
left join b ba on ba.item_code = 'A001'
left join b bb on bb.item_code = 'B001'
```

Or you can use subqueries:

```
select
    a.*,
    (select item_name from b where item_code = 'A001') item_name_a,
    (select item_name from b where item_code = 'B001') item_name_b
from a
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, i forgot to mention some of the stuff, since there will be more than just 2 columns from table A, is there any ways I can get that kinda information instead of hardcoding item_code = 'A001';

Comment: @kownowl: in pure SQL, no. You would need dynamic SQL, which is much more complex.

Comment: what if I wanna get all the columns name and use it as a comparison in another table like.  get all column names from TableA (which will be, A001 as a, B001 as b,..) and use this result to do the following: select name from TableB where code = a; in two seperate query

Answer (score 0):

I GUESS you only want to replace the headings so using information_schema.columns and dynamic sql

```
set @sql = (select concat('select date,',
        aa.gc1,
        ' from (',
        replace(substring(bb.gc2,1,length(bb.gc2) - length('union all')),'union all,','union all '),
        ') s group by date'
        )
from
(
select 
        group_concat(
         'max(case when itemname = ',char(39),itemname,char(39),' then value  end) as ',itemname
         ) gc1
from
(
select itemname , column_name from information_schema.columns 
join   t1 on t1.itemcode = column_name
where table_name = 't'
and column_name in (select distinct itemcode from t1)
) a
) aa
cross join
(
select 
        group_concat(
         'select date,',char(39),itemname,char(39),' as itemname,', column_name,' as value from t  union all'
         ) gc2
from
(
select itemname , column_name from information_schema.columns 
join   t1 on t1.itemcode = column_name
where table_name = 't'
and column_name in (select distinct itemcode from t1)
) b
) bb
) ;

prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
execute sqlstmt;
deallocate prepare sqlstmt;

+------+-------+-------+
| date | candy | Apple |
+------+-------+-------+
| 2020 |     2 |     3 |
+------+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: thank you the reply.  I got a silly question. Is there any ways I can get all the values output in C# or other language without knowing the column's name? like in your example: I wanna do console.writeline and it will print 2020, 2, 3

Comment: Can't help you with c#. If c# is important to you you should say so in the question.

Comment: well but in general, is it possible to turn all those columns into rows instead? like if i have 5 columns in 1 rows: 1,2,3,4,5 and can I select it so that it will display into 1 columns and 5 rows instead?

Comment: The select from sub query b creates a statement which will unpivot, set @sql to that and execute.